# PyQt4 QStackedLayout Switching Layout Error

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I'm trying to get the buttons to work on a user interface I'm making with PyQt4. The windows change but the button only works once before I get the error **NameError: name 'UI2Window' is not defined**. I don't understand why I get this error as the code works fine the first time.

Help fixing this issue / finding a better way to switch layouts is appreciated.

A simplified version on my code is below.

Code from UI1.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import*
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from UI2 import *

class UI1Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.Widget = self.CreateMainLayout()
        self.StackedLayout = QStackedLayout()
        self.StackedLayout.addWidget(self.Widget)
        self.MainWidget = QWidget()
        self.MainWidget.setLayout(self.StackedLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.MainWidget)

    def OnClicked(self):
        Window = UI2Window()
        self.StackedLayout.addWidget(Window)
        self.StackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def CreateMainLayout(self):
        Widget = QWidget()
        self.VLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Button = QPushButton("UI2")
        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.OnClicked)
        self.VLayout.addWidget(self.Button)     
        Widget.setLayout(self.VLayout)
        return Widget

def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ProgramWindow = UI1Window()
    ProgramWindow.show()
    App.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Code from UI".py:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import*
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from UI1 import *

class UI2Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.Widget = self.CreateMainLayout()
        self.StackedLayout = QStackedLayout()
        self.StackedLayout.addWidget(self.Widget)
        self.MainWidget = QWidget()
        self.MainWidget.setLayout(self.StackedLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.MainWidget)

    def OnClicked(self):
        Window = UI1Window()
        self.StackedLayout.addWidget(Window)
        self.StackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def CreateMainLayout(self):
        Widget = QWidget()
        self.VLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Button = QPushButton("UI1")
        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.OnClicked)
        self.VLayout.addWidget(self.Button)     
        Widget.setLayout(self.VLayout)
        return Widget

def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ProgramWindow = UI2Window()
    ProgramWindow.show()
    App.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your goal? Can't you just create your two layouts add them to the QStackedLayout and then switch between index 0 and 1?

Something llike that to keep your code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import*
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from UI2 import *

class UI1Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.StackedLayout = QStackedLayout()
        self.StackedLayout.addWidget(self.CreateMainLayout())
        self.StackedLayout.addWidget(self.CreateMainLayout2())
        self.MainWidget = QWidget()
        self.MainWidget.setLayout(self.StackedLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.MainWidget)

    def OnClicked(self):
        self.StackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(1 if self.StackedLayout.currentIndex() == 0 else 0)

    def CreateMainLayout(self):
        Widget = QWidget()
        self.VLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Button = QPushButton("UI2")
        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.OnClicked)
        self.VLayout.addWidget(self.Button)
        Widget.setLayout(self.VLayout)
        return Widget

    def CreateMainLayout2(self):
        Widget = QWidget()
        self.VLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Button = QPushButton("UI1")
        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.OnClicked)
        self.VLayout.addWidget(self.Button)
        Widget.setLayout(self.VLayout)
        return Widget

def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ProgramWindow = UI1Window()
    ProgramWindow.show()
    App.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I assume you are new in python so please check naming convention [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) ;).

Comment: I want to be able to switch between the layouts while they are in different files as I have 15 layouts I need to link together and having all the code in the same file is not a possibility.

Comment: I ask again. What is your goal? And what do you call a layout? Is it an interface? You have 15 "layouts" so is it a part of a bigger application or is it all the interfaces of your application? What is the meaning of having all your "layout" in the same QStakedLayout?

Comment: Its for a bigger application that i'm making and each interface is saved in a different file. I was trying to use a QStackedLayout to switch between the different interfaces.

Comment: Can't you have a main file that will import all your interfaces files, in this file a main class that will instanciates all the interfaces (eventually stacks them into a QStackedLayout) and it's the main class that will connect signals from every sub interface on wiche you have to change the interface and do what is necessary. In fact, the main class would be a presenter and your interfaces some views in the concept of Model view Presenter (MVP)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working thanks to Controlix's help. The code is below if anyone else needs it.

Window Controller Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import*
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from UI1 import *
from UI2 import *

class Controller(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ImportWindows()
        self.ConnectButtons()
        self.StackedLayout = QStackedLayout()
        self.StackedLayout.addWidget(self.Window1)
        self.StackedLayout.addWidget(self.Window2)
        self.MainWidget = QWidget()
        self.MainWidget.setLayout(self.StackedLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.MainWidget)

    def OnClicked1(self):
        self.StackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def OnClicked2(self):
        self.StackedLayout.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def ImportWindows(self):
        self.Window1 = UI1Window()
        self.Window2 = UI2Window()

    def ConnectButtons(self):
        self.Window1.Button.clicked.connect(self.OnClicked1)
        self.Window2.Button.clicked.connect(self.OnClicked2)

def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ProgramWindow = Controller()
    ProgramWindow.show()
    App.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Code For Windows:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import*
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class UI1Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.StackedLayout = QStackedLayout()
        self.StackedLayout.addWidget(self.CreateMainLayout())
        self.MainWidget = QWidget()
        self.MainWidget.setLayout(self.StackedLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.MainWidget)

    def CreateMainLayout(self):
        Widget = QWidget()
        self.VLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Button = QPushButton("UI2")
        self.VLayout.addWidget(self.Button)     
        Widget.setLayout(self.VLayout)
        return Widget

def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ProgramWindow = UI1Window()
    ProgramWindow.show()
    App.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Good so i guess it's the last comment that help you :) . By the way your way of naming is not at all a python way. I really encourage you to read [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) or some people could not try to help because of that.